# How To Create Data To Use With Rails Application Locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm working on a ruby on rails application locally (`localhost:3000`)

To fully test the functionality and styling of the application I need the application's `tables` populated with fake data.

I am using **Postgres** with the application and would like to use **pgAdmin3** to snoop around in the different `tables` (if possible). I've connected to the pgAdmin3 database I created, I'm just not sure how pgAdmin3 would setup the tables or take data from me. I have already coded the necessary details into the application to communicate with the pgAdmin3 database.

How do I create the tables locally and populate them with data to use, ideally with pgAdmin3? If not I can use the console.

Thanks a lot for having a read :D

Comment: 'If not I can use the console.' why?

Comment: [Using pgAdmin III](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.18/using.html)

Comment: @Cortwave this was for anybody who knew how to follow out the task in console, but were not familiar with pgAdmin3.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate SQL scripts from migrations. You can read more about it in this  [article](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/11/rails-generate-sql-from-migrations.html).